# How to Create PDF in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

Is it possible to generate a PDF using fetched Data in SAPUI5 form?

If yes,
Do we have to use any API or something to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an SAP backend?

If yes, use an adobe form or smartform to generate your pdf. From the sapui5 frontend you need to open a new window with the url pointing to your pdf binary odata service.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) .. Yes That is one possibility but still I just want to use SAPUI5 only .. without ODATA or something like that , can we just fetch it from form and generate PDF directly from the browser??

Comment: You could use the open source jsPDF API, but in my opinion, I would *never* generate PDF's (or other resource heavy tasks) on the client browser. That's what servers are invented for

Answer (score 1):

you can use client-side js libraries like html2canvas and jsPDF.
But these js libraries having some minor bugs.
html2pdf js is the one developed by using both html2canvas and jsPDF and fixed those bugs.
you can download html2pdf js lib by using https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf

and then include this lib in the lib folder in the sapui5 web folder.
include this in your controller.js file.
and use this code to generate PDF.

```
var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
html2pdf(element);
```

Here element-to-print is the ID of Div which you want to generate PDF.
it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate PDF with simple piece of code like below..

```
var data="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"

// This is to convert the binary format of the data to readable format
var bin=atob(data);

// This is to save the data as PDF 
sap.ui.core.util.File.save(bin, "filename", "pdf", "application/pdf");
```